# Atualizar no banco de dados Coordenadas do marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

É o seguinte, eu tenho um mapa onde são gerados vários pontos, traçando assim uma rota...  Só que agora eu preciso editar esses pontos pelo próprio mapa, tipo eu tenho que fazer de uma forma que eu mova os **markers** e automáticamente grave no banco de dados a latitude e longitude do ponto que eu estou mexendo...

[image: RotaMaps]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {

        var stops = [];

        $('.waypoints').each(function() {
            lat = $(this).attr('lat') * 1;
            lon = $(this).attr('lon') * 1;

            stops.push({"Geometry": {"Latitude": lat, "Longitude": lon}});
        });

        console.log(stops);

        var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
        var directionsDisplay = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();

        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
        Tour_startUp(stops);

        window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay);
        window.tour.fitBounds(map);

        if (stops.length > 1)
            window.tour.calcRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });

    function Tour_startUp(stops) {
        if (!window.tour)
        window.tour = {
            updateStops: function(newStops) {
            stops = newStops;
            },
            // map: google map object
            // directionsDisplay: google directionsDisplay object (comes in empty)
            loadMap: function(map, directionsDisplay) {
                var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(-3.056833, -60.004703), // default to Manaus
                mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map.setOptions(myOptions);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            },

            fitBounds: function(map) {
                var bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                // extend bounds for each record
                jQuery.each(stops, function(key, val) {
                    var myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(val.Geometry.Latitude, val.Geometry.Longitude);
                    //console.log(myLatlng);return
                    bounds.extend(myLatlng);
                });
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            },

            calcRoute: function(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
                var batches = [];
                var itemsPerBatch = 10; // google API max = 10 - 1 start, 1 stop, and 8 waypoints
                var itemsCounter = 0;
                var wayptsExist = stops.length > 0;

                while (wayptsExist) {
                    var subBatch = [];
                    var subitemsCounter = 0;

                    for (var j = itemsCounter; j < stops.length; j++) {
                        subitemsCounter++;
                        subBatch.push({
                            location: new window.google.maps.LatLng(stops[j].Geometry.Latitude, stops[j].Geometry.Longitude),
                            stopover: true
                        });
                        if (subitemsCounter == itemsPerBatch)
                            break;
                        console.log(stops[j].Geometry.Latitude);
                    }

                    itemsCounter += subitemsCounter;
                    batches.push(subBatch);
                    wayptsExist = itemsCounter < stops.length;
                    // If it runs again there are still points. Minus 1 before continuing to
                    // start up with end of previous tour leg
                    itemsCounter--;
                }

                // now we should have a 2 dimensional array with a list of a list of waypoints
                var combinedResults;
                var unsortedResults = [{}]; // to hold the counter and the results themselves as they come back, to later sort
                var directionsResultsReturned = 0;

                for (var k = 0; k < batches.length; k++) {

                    var lastIndex = batches[k].length - 1;
                    var start = batches[k][0].location;
                    var end = batches[k][lastIndex].location;

                    // trim first and last entry from array
                    var waypts = [];
                    waypts = batches[k];
                    waypts.splice(0, 1);
                    waypts.splice(waypts.length - 1, 1);

                    var request = {
                        origin: start,
                        destination: end,
                        waypoints: waypts,
                        travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                    };
                    //console.log(request);
                    (function(kk) {
                        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                            if (status == window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                var unsortedResult = {order: kk, result: result
                            };
                            unsortedResults.push(unsortedResult);

                            directionsResultsReturned++;

                            if (directionsResultsReturned == batches.length){ // we've received all the results. put to map
                                // sort the returned values into their correct order
                                unsortedResults.sort(function(a, b) {
                                    return parseFloat(a.order) - parseFloat(b.order);
                                });
                                var count = 0;
                                for (var key in unsortedResults) {
                                    if (unsortedResults[key].result != null) {
                                        if (unsortedResults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                            if (count == 0) // first results. new up the combinedResults object
                                                combinedResults = unsortedResults[key].result;
                                            else {
                                                // only building up legs, overview_path, and bounds in my consolidated object. This is not a complete
                                                // directionResults object, but enough to draw a path on the map, which is all I need
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].legs);
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].overview_path);

                                                combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getNorthEast());
                                                combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getSouthWest());
                                            }
                                            count++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections(combinedResults);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    })(k);
                }
            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Você precisa implementar uma coleção de objetos, e atribuir um Id(mesmo do BD) para cada waypoint e marker, quando você mover um, moverá um objeto, e este objeto precisa de uma callback para enviar a coordenada via json/ajax para o banco de dados.

Comment: Não sei se é o caso de cada waypoint/marker, ou só marker.

Comment: Mas ainda não consegui fazer os marker(waipoints) se moverem... sabes como fazer isso ?

Comment: Estou fazendo as alterações necessárias, para postar uma resposta.

Comment: Cara, aqui temos um problema, as posições iniciais, vem do DOM, se você alterar estas coordenadas, no DOM, permanecerá esta informação, você declarou os pontos como "stops". No mapa quando alterarmos, perderá a consistência dos dados do DOM, seria interessante postar seu HTML, para ver o que podemos fazer para o DOM apresentar a mesma informação quando você arrastar um marker, ou talvez isso nem seja necessário, o que acha?

Comment: `<body>
    <?php
        $waypts='';
        foreach ($listaItinerario as $valor) {
            $waypts.="<input type='hidden' class='waypoints' name='local[]' lat='" . $valor['localLatitudePonto'.$x] . "' lon='" . $valor['localLongitudePonto'.$x] . "'>";
        }    
        /*NESTA LINHA ESTÁ SETADA A LONGOITUDE E LATITUDE DA EMPRESA*/
        $waypts.="<input type='hidden' class='waypoints' name='local[]' lat='-3.122993' lon='-59.980144'>";
        echo $waypts;
    ?>
    <div class="contentMap"></div>    
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="contentMap"></div>    
</body>`

Answer (score 2):

Vou te dar apenas o caminho da coisa, a questão é muito ampla.

Para tornar os markers arrastáveis:

Fonte:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

```
var rendererOptions = { draggable: true}
var directionsDisplay = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
```

Crie um Event listener na inicialização do mapa, para saber que o marker foi alterado:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    salvaNoBd(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
});
```

Declare a função chamada pelo Event Listener:

Fonte:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
function salvaNoBd(coordenadas) {
    $.post( "examplo.php", coordenadas);
}
```

Depois basta tratar as coordenadas enviadas pelo post no php, asp, ou seja lá qual for a linguagem que você usa para comunicar com o banco de dados, um detalhe, é que você precisa implementar uma forma de passar um ID para cada marker, e usar este ID como parâmetro do post também.

Porém da forma que você está fazendo, você está passando para o DOM, já sem nenhuma identificação, e isto você vai precisar implementar no seu código, como não tenho ele na íntegra, não consigo te responder na íntegra.

Comment: Eu entrei no link que vc me passou e consegui fazer roda aqui na minha máquina, mas ele só aceita uma origem, um destino e 8 waypoints... no meu caso, eu tenho rotas com até 40 waypoints... E eu não tow conseguindo adaptar o `draggable: true` no meu código...

Comment: Eu consegui arrastar os markers, mas quando tem mais de 10 markers no mapa é apagados alguns e carrega só os 10 primeiros...

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=pt-br#DraggableDirections

Comment: Na Api V2, utiliza 25, na V3 reduziram para 8, dei uma olhada na net, mas não achei nada interessante, quem sabe, para o seu caso, seja interessante utilizar algum outro webservice.

Comment: Sei que passou bastante tempo, mas utilizo um código para passar de 8 pontos + início e fim. O código em questão está nesta página: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrs_busRoute.html
Pelo o que eu entendi, esse código cria batches de 10 pontos cada, e quando o Maps retorna as rotas, ele junta tudo em uma rota só na exibição. Funciona muito bem.